# Changes via JDBC update are not visible in sequential JDBC select

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a code with this structure (there are a lot of classes, but schema is like this:

```
void f() {
   MyObj o = db.getById(id);
   o.setField1(value);
   db.update(o);
   o = db.getById(id);
   assertEquals(value, o.getField());
}
```

update and get methods use the same data source, incjected with Spring. get works via JdbcTemplate and update just takes connection from dataSource and uses raw JDBC.
Update is marked with @Transactional annotation.
here is a definition of transacion manager from Spring config:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="TransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="TransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

The issue is that if I use update and after it get in different calls of webservice methods, that use them, for exampple, the result is correct and I get updated values.
And if I call them sequentially in one unit-test method after update I don't see updated value.
I can't post the whole read/write code here, because it is large and splitted into many files, but probably you have some ideas how to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush the update before you can see it in the select.

Comment: duffymo, I know how to flush hibernate session, but how to flush connection? Update method consists of many calls to jdbc in different classes (data update, audit update, calls of stored procedures). All of them are in different classes and takes theit own connections. I can't commit after each update operation, because if there is a failure at any step I want to rollback all changes (that's why I have a transactional annotation for the whole method). Also, if the method is with @Transactional, isn't it enought to make all it's changes visible?

Comment: Maybe you need to try another direction: Use Hyperion for a test database without the transaction manager.  Create it with your production schema when you start, run and verify your tests, then blow it away.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
entityManager.refresh(yourEntity);
```

this way, you will get your entities recent instance where you use it after this row.